# How do I get a random object from a class?

Tags: python, class

I want to get a random object from a class, however, I have no idea how to do this. Here's my code:

```
class Pokemon:
    def __init__(self, name, health, damage, move, move2) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage
        self.move = move
        self.move2 = move2

Venusaur = Pokemon('Venusaur', '1295', '124', 'slash', 'venomous spit')
Charizard = Pokemon('Charizard', '1260', '128', 'bite', 'fire breath')
Blastoise = Pokemon('Blastoise', '1320', '113', 'Stomp', 'water gun')
pokemon2 = Pokemon(random.choices(Venusaur,Blastoise,Charizard))

pokemon1 = input('Choose your pokemon\nVenusaur\nCharizard\nBlastoise\n\n')

print(pokemon2)
```

Comment: Check the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) you probably want to use `random.choice` not `random.choices` if I've understood your question

Comment: It would help us understand your question better if you added the output of your code and what you want the output to be.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Do you get any errors? If so, please [edit] your question to include them.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a list with the elements you want to choose from. In your case the Pokemons, and then run `random.choice` on the list.

```
import random

mylist = [Venusaur, Blastoise, Charizard]

print(random.choice(mylist))
```